# How to get rid of error Got an exception - expecting EOF in checkstyle

Tags: pom.xml, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I want to remove this check from checkstyle checks file. Which module is actually responsible for raising this error, so I can mark ignore to this. Moreover, I have changed my checkstyle version to 2.12.1 and added source and target to my javav version as 1.8 but still it is throwing EOF exception on lambda.
Error-

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle_checks.xml</configLocation>
                        <outputFile>build/checkstyle-results/checkstyle_results.xml</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Checkstyle_checks.xml

```
<module name="Checker">

<module name="FileLength">
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
    <property name="max" value="500" />
</module>

<module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="info" />
    <property name="eachLine" value="false" />
</module>


<!-- Checks for long anonymous inner classes. -->

<!-- Sukhmeet starts -->
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="AnonInnerLength">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="max" value="20" />
    </module>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="javaStyle" value="true" />
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="allowInSwitchCase" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="allowClassImports" value="false" />
        <property name="allowStaticMemberImports" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="ClassFanOutComplexity">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="max" value="20" />
    </module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z]$" />
    </module>
    <!-- Comment pattern matcher Not found -->
    <module name="ConstantName">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="applyToPackage" value="true" />
        <property name="applyToPrivate" value="true" />
        <property name="applyToProtected" value="true" />
        <property name="applyToPublic" value="true" />
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="CyclomaticComplexity">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="max" value="7" />
    </module>
    <module name="DeclarationOrder">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <property name="ignoreConstructors" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreMethods" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreModifiers" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="DefaultComesLast">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="DesignForExtension">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyForInitializerPad">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyStatement">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    </module>
    <module name="EqualsAvoidNull">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="ignoreEqualsIgnoreCase" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="FallThrough">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="checkLastCaseGroup" value="false" />
        <!-- <property name="reliefPattern" value="" /> -->
    </module>

    <module name="FinalClass">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="FinalLocalVariable">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    </module>
    <module name="HiddenField">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="ignoreAbstractMethods" value="True" />
        <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="True" />
        <!-- <property name="ignoreFormat" value="" /> -->
        <property name="ignoreSetter" value="True" />
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF" />
    </module>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <!-- page 1 ends -->
    <module name="IllegalCatch">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="illegalClassNames" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalImport">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="illegalPkgs" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="classes" value="java.lang.Boolean " />
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalThrows">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="warningdMethodNames" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="illegalClassNames" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="InnerTypeLast">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="allowMarkerInterfaces" value="true" />
    </module>
    <module name="JavaNCSS">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="classMaximum" value="400" />
        <property name="fileMaximum" value="500" />
        <property name="methodMaximum" value="40" />
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="maxLineLength" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="ignorePattern"
            value="^\s*\*\s*[^\s]+.+$|^@|^\s*/\*.*\*/|^\s*//.*|^\s*@|^\s*import" />
        <property name="max" value="120" />
        <!-- <property name="tabWidth" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="^([a-z]|[l] [_])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="applyToPackage" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToPrivate" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToProtected" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToPublic" value="True" />
        <property name="format" value="^([a-z]|[m][_])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="countEmpty" value="true" />
        <property name="max" value="50" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="allowClassName" value="False" />
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="MethodParamPad">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
  <!--          <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="Default" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z]$" />
    </module>
    <module name="MissingDeprecated">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    </module>
    <module name="MissingOverride">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="javaFiveCompatibility" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="ModifiedControlVariable">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="ModifierOrder">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    </module>
    <module name="MultipleStringLiterals">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="allowedDuplicates" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="warningOccurrenceContext" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="warningStringsRegexp" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value=""/> -->
    </module>
    <module name="NestedForDepth">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="max" value="3" />
    </module>
    <module name="NestedIfDepth">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="max" value="1" />
    </module>
    <module name="NestedTryDepth">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="max" value="1" />
    </module>
    <module name="NoFinalizer">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    <!--    <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="Default" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="Default" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="NPathComplexity">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="max" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="OuterTypeNumber">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="max" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="PackageAnnotation">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
    </module>
    <module name="PackageDeclaration">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="ignoreDirectoryName" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="PackageName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="[a-z]+(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterAssignment">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="format" value="^([a-z]|[a][_])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterNumber">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="max" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantImport">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="allowSubclasses" value="false" />
        <property name="allowUnchecked" value="false" />
        <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true" />
    </module>
    <module name="ReturnCount">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="format" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="max" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="StaticVariableName">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <property name="applyToPackage" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToPrivate" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToProtected" value="True" />
        <property name="applyToPublic" value="True" />
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </module>
    <module name="StringLiteralEquality">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="SuperClone">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="SuperFinalize">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="TrailingComment">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <property name="format" value="^[\s\}\);]*$" />
        <!-- <property name="legalComment" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="TypecastParenPad">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <!-- <property name="option" value="" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="UncommentedMain">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
        <!-- <property name="excludedClasses" value="" /> -->
    </module>
    <module name="UnnecessaryParentheses">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    </module>
    <module name="UnusedImports">
        <property name="severity" value="info" />
        <property name="processJavadoc" value="false" />
    </module>
    <module name="UpperEll">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    </module>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
        <property name="severity" value="error" />
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
        <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="false" />
        <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="false" />
        <!-- <property name="tokens" value="" /> -->
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Please provide the exception message you are getting. It should reference the file that is causing the issue. Also you should format your config file and ensure it is valid XML.

Comment: @rveach Error added in question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not seeing it. I would need to see the full stack trace to help.